# React Native TouchableHighlight Font Color Text Change

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

how do TouchableHighlight handles the color of the text when tap. I already did it on the backgroundColor using underLayColor. Here's my code:

```
<TouchableHighlight
                        style={{ borderRadius: 5}}
                        underlayColor="#ffffff"
                        onPress={this.onLoadPress}>
                            <View style={[styles.buttonBox, styles.btnEditProfile]}>
                                <Text style={styles.btnEditProfileText}>
                                    Edit Profile
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can only change the underlayColor as you've mentioned. However, I'm thinking you may be able to get the affect you want using animation. I don't have time to figure it out for you though, sorry... http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#content

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this myself. And using `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` props of `TouchableWithoutFeedback` causes a little delay that becomes glitchy if you use that on a component that receives frequent taps. However, that delay doesn't occur when you use `onShowUnderlay` and `onHideUnderlay` props of `TouchableHighlight` itself.

**P.S.** your `TouchableHighlight` component should have an `onPress` property for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a working example I have for changing the Text color onPressIn

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, Pressable } from "react-native";

export function MyButton(props) {
    const { title, onPress } = props
    const [labelColor, setLabelColor] = useState('white')
    return (
        <Pressable 
        onPress={onPress} 
        onPressIn={ () => setLabelColor('rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)')} 
        onPressOut={ () => setLabelColor('rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)')}
        style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={[styles.label, {color:labelColor}]}>{title}</Text>
        </Pressable>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        borderRadius: "50%",
        backgroundColor: '#0066FF',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 24,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        marginHorizontal: 24.0,
        marginVertical: 16.0,
    },
    label: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: '700',
    },
})
```

[image: Normal state]

[image: Highlighted state]

Answer (score -1):

The TouchableHighlight has all the props of TouchableWithoutFeedback. TouchableWithoutFeedback has the onPressIn and onPressOut props which can receive a function (basically like onMouseDown and onMouseUp). You can use those methods to change a state which will change the style of the text. [Here is a working example.](https://rnplay.org/apps/mMVsew)

Comment: Link to the example is dead

Comment: hey .. did you find a solution for this yet ? if you did please answer your question .. thanks